"colcon build" freezes screen
I have a ROS2-Humble workspace. I'm trying to build workspace with colcon build --symlink-install. It is starting to building packages but when it comes to one specific package (rmf_fleet_adapter), screen is freezing. I've searched solutions but non of them has worked yet.
I'm waiting at least 15 minutes every time, but I can't get any response from my computer. I have to reboot it every time because of freezing of the screen.
These are the things which I've tried so far:
colcon build --symlink-install --packages-select rmf_fleet_adapter
colcon build --symlink-install --parallel-workers 1 --packages-select rmf_fleet_adapter
colcon build --symlink-install --executor sequential --packages-select rmf_fleet_adapter
colcon build --symlink-install --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --executor sequential --packages-select rmf_fleet_adapter
Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

It's likely that you're running out of some resource such as memory or storage space, up bandwidth etc  you'll need to give more information about your system, both hardware and software to get effective help. And share any debugging or changes in behavior between your trials. Also describe your symptoms in more details. For example does it recover after some amount of time, is it other responsive? Do you get crash reports?

I edited my post, thank you. Let me know if this information aren't enough

In the future please copy and paste text output, not screenshot so it's searchable.
I don't see anything in there about RAM availability. It would be good to watch your RAM usage when you're trying to do the compile. I see you only have 2GB of swap. Do you have any messages in dmesg potentially related to OOM killer being activate?

You were right, it was related to RAM. Thank you...

It is solved with:
export MAKEFLAGS="-j 1"
colcon build --executor sequential


it seems that you are out of memory while building.
You could try building with as less ram usage as possible with:
export MAKEFLAGS="-j 1"
colcon build --executor sequential

source
this will build your workspace with only one core and one package at a time. You can also use "-j N" to use N cores.
I had a similar problem and this worked for me.
Be aware that building will take a lot of time.
EDIT: to have a single command with the core option it is possible to do:
MAKEFLAGS="-j 1" colcon build ...


Thank you, it worked perfectly...
I think it is for the usable core number, right?

Instead of using 2 different command, can we add "export MAKEFLAGS="-j 1"" as a parameter at the end of "colcon build --executor sequential"?

Hi @yigitboracagiran , glad it worked! in the documentation I linked above it states that for this argument it must be used an environment variable.
Using --cmake-args does not work, maybe there is a way I didn't find

I couldn't find it either, looks like we'll continue to change environment variable...

Given that the flag solved your problem you can mark the answer as accepted if you want :)

Sorry, I'm new to this forum, I didn't know how to accept the answer. Now it should be accepted :)

@yigitboracagiran Hi, I found a way to use a single command to both compile and use only N cores.
you have to add MAKEFLAGS="-j N" before the colcon build command, see the edit of the original answer

Thanks for the update, first thing tomorrow I'll look into it :)

Note: You can change the variable, it doesn't need to be 1.
Be aware that you will increase the chance of freezing every time you increase the variable but in the other hands, building time will be increase every time you decrease the variable. You can see the effect of building the project on your system with htop command in another terminal.
