examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_server hanging on my Raspberry pi with ROS2
Hey guys I’ve just started playing with the ROS2 since last week, and I’ve been following all the documentation tutorials in general. I finally finished the CLI tutorials, and started working on the Client Libraries tutorials. And the one that I’m currently on is the “Using colcon to build packages”. (FYI I’m using ROS2 Foxy).
These were the following steps that I followed when I ssh'd to my raspberry pi:
I first installed ColCon via this command:
sudo apt install python3-colcon-common-extensions
The tutorial then instructed me to create a directory to hold my workspace:
mkdir -p ~/ros2_ws/src
cd ~/ros2_ws

Within my directory I had to clone the examples repository:
git clone https://github.com/ros2/examples src/examples -b foxy
Once I've completed these steps I then had to run the following command in order to build Colcon in my root directory:
colcon build --symlink-install
When doing the above my raspberry pi began to crash after consistently doing 4 processes at the same time. I looked throughout many forums to solve this issue, and found one where a user instead used the following command to stop the persistent crashing:
colcon build --symlink-install --executor sequential
When doing this I was able to build one package, however it continues to freeze when I try to build the server:

I've then started looking at the logs, and in truth I am not sure what it necessarily means but this could help those in helping me figure out the problem.
This was found within the events log for the build:

When it comes to the logs, I just want to clarify that I am not sure I am looking at the right ones, what I did was I opened the logs directory then opened the following build:
build_2024-08-08_17-33-59
within the build directory I then opened the following:
events.log
Which showed the above image.
I also want to clarify, that the time jump between the client and the server was quite drastic:

The time events here were quite a shock in my opinion.
The link to the tutorial is here: https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Colcon-Tutorial.html
I've also tried these solutions that people used to try and solve this problem but none of this seems to work for me: https://answers.ros.org/question/407554/colcon-build-freeze-a-raspberry-pi/

Colcon builds whatever is in you workspace. Please identify the minimum workspace that reproduces your problem and then edit your question to include instructions for how to reproduce the problem, including full commands and their outputs. Most likely this is an issue related to the package in your workspace which is 50% of the way through the topological order.

I updated your title to be more representative. Please copy and past console output instead of screenshotting. Otherwise it's not searchable nor copy and pasteable. Which leads to quick errors.

14 seconds doesn't sound like it's really frozen. Are you sure it's not just taking a little bit of time to compile? The Raspberry Pi isn't very powerful computationally.

Can you make sure you're not running out of memory someone else was having a similar issue recently: https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/112554/colcon-build-freezes-screen/112568#112568

I'll make sure im not running out of memory, and will try out their approach by just using 1 core

The link that was posted in the comments of my question, had a command which was this:
export MAKEFLAGS="-j 1"
colcon build --executor sequential

If anyone is having trouble with building Colcon on the Raspberry pi 3B the above command will run the build with 1 core of the cpu which will not put stress on your memory. I was able to build everything with Colcon in under 45 minutes.
I want to give thanks to Tully for helping and providing a link to the solution, that was needed for me to properly build Colcon with no problem.
